# how to change month info text to number?

Tags: java, datetime, widget, swt, eclipse-rcp

I created a DateTime widget. My image is here:

[image]

But I want to display month info as number (09 instead of Eylül(TR)/September(EN))

My code is below:

```
DateTime dateTimeStart = new DateTime(filterComposite, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.LONG);
RowData rdStartDate = new RowData();
dateTimeStart.setLayoutData(rdStartDate);
```

How can I do this? Can anybody give some advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only choices you have are the `SWT.SHORT`, `SWT.MEDIUM` and `SWT.LONG` styles.

Exactly how these styles are interpreted will also vary between platforms. For example on Macs SWT.MEDIUM and SWT.LONG are the same.

Comment: if I want to use MEDIUM, can I change "." to "/" ?

Comment: You can't change anything. You just get the three styles and that is it. As mentioned in the other answer there are various other controls with more options.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of custom library widgets that contains pretty decent time widgets, for me the best is
http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php
example from project site:

```
CDateTime cdt = new CDateTime(parent, CDT.BORDER | CDT.DROP_DOWN);
cdt.setPattern("'Meeting on' EEEE, MM d '@' h:mm 'in the'a");
```

Patter is in format from SimpleDateFormat:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: What can I do to use Nebula widget? When I add CDateTime definition in my code, programme coluld not define the class.

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/nebula/snapshot/repository.zip extract jars and add them to your classpath